# How to show datalable on last value of arearange series

Tags: highcharts

I need to show datalable on last value of arearange series in the following piece of code, same as described in [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.dataLabels) for line series.

```
$(function () {

var ranges = [
        [1246406400000, 14, 27],
        [1246492800000, 13, 17],
        [1246579200000, 15, 29],
        [1246665600000, 16, 30],
        [1246752000000, 18, 25]         
    ];


    $('#container').highcharts({

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        series: [ {
            name: 'Range',
            data: ranges,
            type: 'arearange',
            lineWidth: 0,
            linkedTo: ':previous',
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            fillOpacity: 0.3,
            zIndex: 0
        }]

    });
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle for the above given code: http://jsfiddle.net/xG3QF/1/

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it, last value should be passed as object using x, low, high as explained [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/range-series).

```
   {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'left',
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                x: 3,
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                overflow: true,
                crop: false
            },
            x: 1246752000000,
        low:18,
        high:25
        }
```

updated jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/xG3QF/2/